# Accessing native headers on StompHeaderAccessor

Tags: java, spring, stomp

I'm building a chat server.  I am using the following code to extract the username of a new user connection.  It works, but it doesn't feel like the proper way to do this.  How do I do this properly?

```
  @EventListener
  public void handleWebSocketConnectListener(SessionConnectedEvent event) {
    StompHeaderAccessor stompAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
    GenericMessage connectHeader = (GenericMessage)stompAccessor.getHeader(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.CONNECT_MESSAGE_HEADER);    // FIXME find a way to pass the username to the server
    Map<String, List<String>> nativeHeaders = (Map<String, List<String>>) connectHeader.getHeaders().get(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS);

    String login = nativeHeaders.get("login").get(0);
    String sessionId = stompAccessor.getSessionId();

    logger.info("Chat connection by user <{}> with sessionId <{}>", login, sessionId);
  }
}
```